# Is it possible to change command button design of Primefaces FileUpload Component?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I use the PrimeFaces p:uploadFile in that way:

```
<p:fileUpload value="#{myBean.myFile}" mode="simple" style="width:500px;" />
```

How can I change the design of the command button in this component? As default,  the button looks like a MS Windows command button (please, look at this showcase: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/file/upload/basic.xhtml).

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can change the appearance of a Primefaces component.

1. By changing the jQuery UI Theme in the web.xml

   Have a look at [Primefaces Themes](http://www.primefaces.org/themes) for more informations.

This would change your whole Primefaces component styles though. To change the style for some specific components, we need to override CSS classes.

For the FileUpload CommandButton this would be:

```
.ui-fileupload-buttonbar .ui-button {
        background-color: green !important; /*Only an example*/
}
```

Make sure to append `!important` to your style changes. Otherwise it won't get changed.

Comment: the `!important` is a bad practice, you should arrange your CSS calls to make sure that the cascade is working fine, you should never you use `!important` in overriding your PrimeFaces style.

Comment: Thats true... To make it work without `!important` you need to adjust your facets to let them load in the right order. @HatemAlimam btw. the contact form on your homepage isn't working.

Comment: I know, I'm updating the SSL heartbleed bug on my server :)